# Which directory should I save a .pgpass file in when connecting to Postgresql from Python in Anaconda?

Tags: python, postgresql, anaconda, spyder

I've saved a .pgpass (properly configured) file in

```
`/Users/username/`

`/anaconda`

`/anaconda/bin/`
```

but the postgresql connection still requests my username and password. I'm using Anaconda and Spyder IDE. Where should I save the .pgpass file?

Answer (score 9):

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) says:

- The program must be using the C client library `libpq` to connect to PostgreSQL (the JDBC driver, for example, doesn't use `libpq`).
- The `.pgpass` file must be in the home directory of the user that owns the process which uses `libpq` to connect to PostgreSQL.
- You can override the default location by either putting the variable `PGPASSFILE` in the process' environment or (from v10 on) with the connection parameter `passfile`.
- The `.pgpass` file must have permissions 0600 or less.

Answer (score 3):

Check permissions. The `.pgpass` file has to have no group nor other permissions:

```
chmod u-x,go-rwx ~/.pgpass
```

A command line psql client would actually warn you about it:
`WARNING: password file "/home/tometzky/.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less`

Comment: My .pgpass file has permissions 0600. The connection just doesn't recognize that the file exists.